# Dropdown link not working in navigation bar | bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I'm not able to click on the dropdown options which are available in my navigation bar. I'm using bootstrap classes for creating the navigation menu. Tried some examples which are already there in google but still not getting success.

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #7910C6">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="HomePage.aspx">Demo AUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="act"><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Frames & Windows<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="Frames.aspx">Frames</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="Windows.aspx">Windows</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please correct me if i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried above HTML and I am able to click on the links. No problem for me.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM The issue is same code is working in all the pages except one and i'm not able to figure out why such thing is happening

Comment: It started working the issue was with the bootstrap.js file

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Even i have tried the same thing. The issue is same code is working in all the pages except one and i'm not able to figure out why such thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please add  below bootstrap js link above  tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  </head>

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #7910C6">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Demo AUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="act"><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Frames & Windows<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="Frames.aspx">Frames</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="Windows.aspx">Windows</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


  <body>
<h1 class="text-success">  testing</h1>
   <!-- ahiya bootstrap na code lakhjo -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It started working the issue was with the bootstrap.js file

Comment: please run code snippet ...code are perfectly working

Comment: please verify my ans.. i will try to solve close thread problem